# Problems with setting JRE_HOME for a d3web installation

Tags: java, java-home, d3web

I have to use d3web. The tutorial gives me the following hint regarding the installation of d3web

[image]

So, I set the values of these variables like displayed in the picture.
[image]

[image]

But when starting the starting the startup.bat I receive a message stating that I have not set the values of JRE_HOME nor JAVA_HOME.

[image]

Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: Also set those variables as system variables as well.. most of the time restart is required to take this changes

Comment: in command prompt, if you execute SET are you able to see the JAVA_HOME/JRE_HOME listed?

Comment: problem solved. Thank you for your help :)